# Disk space for non-persisted In-Memory tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, disk-space, memory-optimized-tables

I have a database on a SQL Server 2014 SP2, CU5 Enterprise edition.

The database has a memory optimized filegroup. There are two tables in it, both are set to `DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY` and have a low bucket count (e.g. 512).

I don't remember what the initial disk space of this file was, but some time ago it allocated 4 GB and has since grown to ~7 GB. When I look in the filestream files with a hex editor, it seems that they contain data from a (partitioned) datawarehouse table in the same database, but this could be due to instant file initialisation.

- Is there a way to shrink the filegroup?
- Why does the in-memory filegroup take up so much space?
- How can I verify, if (and which) other tables are using the space, since `SELECT * FROM sys.indexes AS i WHERE i.data_space_id = 8 -- = the in_memory filegroup` does not return anything

Comment: Just found https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3339/monitor-memory-consumption-for-sql-server-memory-optimized-tables/ for my third question, but  sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats shows only my two tables with only a few hundred KB...

Comment: Not possible to control the size of a memory-optimized file group, and that includes the size of any containers and/or checkpoint file pairs within those containers. 

Even if you have schema-only memory-optimized tables, the engine pre-allocates some files on disk. 

Are you doing tlog backups for this db? 

It's not possible for non-memory-optimized tables to be placed on data/delta files.